# Mysql Database is crashing on a .EXE vb.net console file

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create table in MYSQL database using vb.net console applicaiton, I already tried running it using Visual Studio 2012 and it is running smoothly but when i tried creating a .EXE file using VS 2012's build then I copied the file on bin/debug it fails to run as I deploy it to another machine (I already installed MYSQL connect 6.8.3 and .NET framework in the machine). I already tried to debug it, the problem occurs where i incorporate variable in my query.

Here is the code.

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    toCreateTable()
End Sub

Private Sub toCreateTable()

    Dim varString As String = "tablenaming"

    Dim Query As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=10.4.26.101; user=prolog;  database=db_prolog; port=3306; password=n0viru$;")
    con.Open()

    Query = "CREATE TABLE  '" & varString & "' ( usernames varchar(50) ) "

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) Then

    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

End Module

Here is the error.

```
unhandled exception: mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manula that correspons to you MySQL server version for the right syntas to user near ''tblenaming' (usernames varchar(50)) )' at line 1
at mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlstream.readpacket()
at mysql.data.mysqlclient.nativdriver.getresult(int32& statementId, int32& affected Rows, int 64& insertedId)

at mysql.data.mysqlclient.driver.getresult(int32 statementId, Boolean force)
at mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqldatareader.nextresult()
at mysql.data.mysqlcommand.executereader(commandbehavior behavior))
at mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand.executenonquery()
at consolapplication15.module1.toCreateTable()
at consoleapplication.module1.main()
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySql the default character used to encapsulate the names of tables or columns is the backtick. Not the single quote. Try to change your code to

```
Query = "CREATE TABLE `" & varString & "` ( usernames varchar(50) ) "
```

Type the backtick keeping pressed the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and press <kbd>096</kbd> on the numeric keyboard

Comment: Glad to be of help and welcome to StackOverflow. Just remember to accept/upvote the answers that help you to solve your problems.